# Data Not showing from Google Weather API also Toast not showing

Tags: android, weather-api

i have been following new boston android series and in XML parsing tutorial i m facing an issue.
data is not showing.also no opertation showing on button click on real device.
code is :
weatherXMLParsing class

```
    package com.ss;

import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.datatype.Duration;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.text.InputFilter.LengthFilter;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WeatherXMLParsing extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    static final String baseURL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=rajasthan,jaipur&mode=xml";
    TextView tvCity, tvState;
    EditText etCity, etState;
    Button bWeather;
    TextView tvWeather;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.weather);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
        tvCity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCity);
        tvState = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvState);
        etCity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCity);
        etState = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etState);
        bWeather = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btWeather);
        tvWeather = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvWeather);
        bWeather.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(WeatherXMLParsing.this, "thanks for pressing",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        String c = etCity.getText().toString();
        String s = etState.getText().toString();
        // StringBuilder URL = new StringBuilder(baseURL);
        // URL.append(c+","+s+"&mode=xml");

        /*
         * System.out.print(fullurl +"========");
         * System.out.println(URL.toString());
         */

        try {
            java.net.URL website = new URL(baseURL);

            // getting xmlreader for parsing
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
            HandlingXMLStuff doingWork = new HandlingXMLStuff();
            xr.setContentHandler(doingWork);
            xr.parse(new InputSource(website.openStream()));

            String information = doingWork.getInformation();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            tvWeather.setText("ERROR" + e.toString());
            Dialog d   = new Dialog(this);
            d.setTitle("ERROR"+e.toString());
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            d.setContentView(tv);
        }

    }

}
```

HandliingStuff

```
package com.ss;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class HandlingXMLStuff extends DefaultHandler{


    XMLDataCollected info = new XMLDataCollected();

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        //super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);


        if(localName.equals("city"))
        {
            String city = attributes.getValue("name");
            info.setCity(city);

        }
        else if(localName.equals("temperature"))
        {
            String temp = attributes.getValue("value");

            info.setTemp(temp);
        }
    }

    public String getInformation() {
        return info.dataToString();
    }
}
```

XMLDataCollected

```
package com.ss;

public class XMLDataCollected {

    String temp = "";
    String city = "";

    public void setCity(String c) {
        city = c;
    }

    public void setTemp(String tempr) {
        temp = tempr;
    }

    public String dataToString() {
        return "In "+city +" the current temrature in faranhite is " +temp+" degrees";
    }

}
```

Comment: downvotes please comment for downvotes .or answer if you think its not a question

Comment: There is a lot of code here, could you narrow this down to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Rick .ok let me summarize.i m getting city and state from User input.onclick of a button WeatherXMLParsing class and parsing it through HandlingXMLStuff.that you can see it has a method getInformation .i tried to do this using static xml but its also not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to learn the basic about fetching the data from the server. Make use of [asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for calling the api.

Refer this for an [example](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/05/build-weather-app-json-http-android.html)

Comment: i m following new boston's tutorial and in that its working fine.

Comment: can you plz tell me where is the issue in this with SAX parser

Answer (score 0):

You need to call setOnClickListener for each button.  You only call it once for one button.

I suggest you start by using a Toast or writing a long message in your on click listener(s) to be sure that you are actually executing the listener.  Take this out once the program is working.

Fahim is also correct.  Any time you access the net you must do it in a background thread or your user-interface will lock up.  [asyncTask is the easiest way to create the background thread you need.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: i have only one button and i have set for it .and yeah i know about using aysn task.but for the tutorial i m follwing in that he has done without asyn so i m trying to that.